# Azure Function not triggering after deployment. Works locally

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have created an Azure Function which Uses Topic/Subscription. It works on local. But when I deploy it on azure, it receives messages and it stays in Active Messages. It doesn't process the message.

```
 [Function("MyServiceBusTopicTriggerSubscription")]
    public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("Topic", 
                                                "Sub", Connection = "AzureServiceBus")]string queueMessage, 
                                                ILogger log, FunctionContext context)
    {
        // get configuration
        var config = ConfigurationService.GetConfiguration(ref context);
    }
```

I have checked the settings in local.env.settings.json, it has got the proper AzureServiceBus connection string.

Comment: What SDK is this? How your configuration is set up for the Functions App?

Comment: I am using Framework 5.0. Contacted Microsoft Support. They told me to upgrade it to Framework 6.0 and told to check it again

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced the same problem and it’s working locally but not working on the azure portal. I solved this issue by adding a connection string in configure section. Did you checked the connection string in Configure section? If no, please add the connection string in configure section.

[image]

In my case connection string is _servicebusConnectionstring
[image]

Azure function code and read connection string from local.setting.json file.

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace _73373348_FunctionApp19
{
    public class Function1
    {
        
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> log)
        {
            _logger = log;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("message_topic", "subscription_topic", Connection = "_servicebusConnectionString")]string mySbMsg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message from service bus is :- ", mySbMsg);
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
        }
    }
}
```

output
[image]

Application Insights
[image]

[image]

Comment: Connection string is already there in config file. It is defined on Configuration Section in the azure portal too.

Comment: This worked for me! I stumbled upon another place to see errors. When you access your azure function from the azure website if you wait a few seconds an error could pop up at the top of the screen if there are any deployment errors. For example, an error displayed for me indicating I was missing a configuration/app setting variable.